Improving pose estimation accuracy of fiducial markers
I want a manipulator to detect and grasp an object.
I'm trying to do it by attaching a fiducial marker (AprilTag) near the object, and use vision system and marker pose estimation to get the position of the object w.r.t the robot.
It seems that the pose estimation accuracy of marker is not good enough, and I'm getting ~10 mm error.

is there a fiducial marker with high pose estimation accuracy?
is there any methods to improve pose estimation accuracy?

I'm hoping to use markers instead of deeplearning-based methods for the ease of implementation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

You haven't said what your vision system is. I'd start by checking what it is returning to the rest of your robot system. Is there a way to see its idea of what it's looking at? If the camera is way out of focus, or otherwise low resolution, then a centimeter of fuzziness will result in a cm of uncertainty.
